# How to add an attribute to each option of dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dropdown list:

```
<select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Bla">Bla</option>
    <option value="Foo">Foo</option>
</select>
```

Using jQuery I want to modify my list by enumerating each option by adding an custom attribute `level` so my select will look like that and need to skip the first option of the list:

```
<select>
    <option value=""></option> //skipping the first one
    <option value="Bla" level="1">Bla</option>
    <option value="Foo" level="2">Foo</option>
</select>
```

How can I do that with jQuery?

Comment: So what you want to do with `jQuery` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over all the option with index 1 to n using `$('select option:gt(0)')`:

```
$('select option:gt(0)').attr('level',function(i){
   return i+1;
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqrspzoy/)**

**or**

```
$('select option:gt(0)').each(function(i){
   $(this).attr('level',i+1)
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkwq0bpa/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').children('option').each(function(index, element) {
  if (index) $(element).attr('level', index);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.attr()`

```
$('select option:not(:first-child)').attr('level', function (i) {
    return i + 1
})
```

Answer (score 1):

its better to use `data-*` attribute provided by `html5`:

```js
$('select option').filter(':not(:first)').attr('data-level', function(i) {
  return $(this).index();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select>
  <option value=""></option> <!--this has index = 0-->
  <option value="Bla">Bla</option><!--this has index = 1-->
  <option value="Foo">Foo</option><!--this has index = 2-->
</select>
```

As you can see in the js code there is the use of `attr()` method of jQuery, and you can notice that it accepts a callback function to return the attribute value with some operation if needed.
In this specific case we are using `.index()` of the `option` available in the given `select` and in the callback a return statement is necessary to apply the attribute.

Comment: can you please make me understand why you returning ` return $(this).index();` and if I dont then what problem will I get?

Comment: @SpringLearner `.index()` returns the position index like you can see that in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('select option').each(function(index,item){
   if(index>0)
   {
      $(item).attr('level',index);
   }
})
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vu1or488/)